# How to convert object to array in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming

I have got object of arrays properties .

```
const data = {
test:["1","2"],
test2:["1","2"]

}
```

I am trying to convert this format. I am using Object.values(data) where I can only array . I need to get this format.

My trying code :

let output =  Object.values(data)

```
output : [{test:[{label:"1",value:"1"},{label:"2",value:"2"}]},{test2:[{label:"1",value:"1"},{label:"2",value:"2"}]]
```

Comment: Is `Object.values()` the only thing you've tried? Have you tried any other code? (if so, please add it)

Comment: I just only array of sub-arrays , but did not get any logic how it would be implemented ?

Comment: will the arrays inside your object always consist of two elements, or can there be more?

Comment: can I use Object.entries for getting both of arrays

Comment: my question is about the `["1", "2"]` values in your object. It appears that you want to make an array of objects from it `[{label:"1",value:"2"}]`. But what if you have an array like `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`, should you get `[{label:"1",value:"2"}, {label:"3",value:"4"}]` ? Or can you never have an array that takes the shape of `["1", "2", "3", "4"]` in the first place? I'm asking this as you have an array with one object in it (what is the point of the array?)

Comment: just edit my output , it was mistake from me

Comment: so do `label` and `value` take the same value in the object?

Comment: it would be same value , yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use `Object.entries` to get access to the keys (*"test"*, *"test2"*, etc) and values (arrays) then map the values to an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties (based on the *value*).

Something like this...

```js
const data = {
  test: ["1", "2"],
  test2: ["1", "2"]
}

let output = Object.entries(data).map(([ key, values ]) => ({
  [key]: values.map(v => ({ label: v, value: v }))
}))

console.info(output)
```

Comment: your outptut doesn't match with my output . it would be {
    "test2":[ {
      "label": "1",
      "value": "2"
    }]
  } like this

Comment: @sujon oh, you want a redundant array? That's kinda weird but sure, that's pretty easy. I'll update my answer

Comment: @sujon fixed but you should really work on providing the correct information up-front as well as what you already tried

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061331/how-to-filter-array-of-object-to-array-of-another-objects-in-javascript

Comment: @sujon no, because it has been deleted

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.entries` and `map` to build the array.

```js
const format = obj =>
  Object.entries(obj).map(([key, arr]) => ({
    [key]: arr.map(value => ({
      label: value, value
    }))
  }));

const data = {
  test: ["1", "2"],
  test2: ["1", "2"]
};

console.log(format(data));
```

Comment: can you look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61061331/how-to-filter-array-of-object-to-array-of-another-objects-in-javascript